# How to Auto Select Size Attribute [Multi Sizes] in Magento 2.4.6 If anyone Exists

Tags: php, web, e-commerce, magento2, magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.6, and I need to show the product view page by three different size attributes (Euro, Regular, and US) for configurable products. I created the multi size attributes for that specific product in
[cms page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heLiG.png)

When the user selects any of the attributes, another attribute strikes out automatically and is shown in the appropriate size. Now my issue is that when the user click the Add to Cart button, a validation error occurs (the field is required), as shown in
[Product View Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cleL.png)

So the user is forced to select each size attribute manually, one by one.

I just need to make the attribute select automatically when the user selects any one of the size attributes.